# Why do different machines receive updates at different times?

Tags: fedora, dnf

Out of curiosity:

I run two Fedora Workstations, one at work and one at home. I recently noticed that updates (kernel, etc.) consistently show up on my machine at work about a day earlier. Does anybody know the reason for the discrepancy? Is this the time that it takes to roll out the updates to all mirrors? I have set dnf on my machines to determine the fastest mirror, if that makes any difference.

Comment: How often do you synchronize your repositories? Do you do it automatically via a desktop GUI/administration tool?

Comment: @lgeorget I usually run `dnf upgrade --refresh` once after i have booted the machine and once before i turn it off. E.g. yesterday I saw kernel version 10.8 show up on my workmachine in the evening. To get that on my home machine now, i need to enable the `updates-testing` repo, that's already a timespan of >12h.

Comment: Wait, does that mean you don't have the same repositories enabled on your two workstations? Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @lgeorget No, the repos are the same. I just meant to say that on my work machine, the new kernel version shows up in the `updates` repo since yesterday, on my home machine right now (~16h later) the new kernel version doesn't show up, *unless* i enable the `updates-testing` repo. My assumption is that the mirror my home machine identifies as fastest simply lags behind roughly 24h.

Comment: Ah, ok! Got it. If you don't use the same mirrors on the two workstations, then yes, it means that the mirrors are not synchronized with their own update servers at the same time.